# Transition on position change in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a transition on an element when I am changing its position (from `static` to `fixed`).

I tried doing a transition: `transition: position 2s linear;` but it actually doesn't do anything. Is there anything else I could try ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give more details on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The position property is not animatable/transitionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the declaration properly, however you can only transition numeric values - this is because transition will calculate inbetween steps for the two values you're transitioning between, and while 0% and 100% have steps inbetween, there is no valuefor three-quarters-fixed-one-quarter-static.

The [working draft for the transition shorthand](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#animatable-types) has a few pointers on what can reasonably be animated.

In other words, you won't be able to animate this with transition, so the only possible way is likely through JS at this point. With the code you provided, that is impossible to say, though.